# What are the protocols that are used in teamviewer audio chat?

Tags: audio, protocols, voip, teamviewer

My country is blocking VOIP, so basically I can't make audio or video chats. However when using Teamviewer, it's always possible to make audio and video conferences, so what I want to know is how is that possible, and what are exactly the VOIP protocols used to allow me chat in audio and video?

I knew from a previous question that the teamviewer is a closed source but I'm still waiting for any protocols that would work even if the VOIP is blocked.

Regards.

Comment: Does it worked?

Answer (score -1):

If your network / country network do support for WebRTC then this would help.

RTC - Real time communication is a protocol, everything works on this only. Whether it is skype, teamviewer, whatsapp video call etc.

Setup you own WebRTC server and obtain absolute URL with its protocol. Make sure that has to be work within your network only. When your devices are in wifi / network. They can connect each other through absolute URL.

Refer - https://github.com/ISBX/apprtc-ios/blob/master/README.md